# “An Introduction to Manifolds”, Loring W.Tu, Example 8.19

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Loring Tu's “An Introduction to Manifolds”, P95, Example 8.19

[image]

My problem is: How to verify that the final sentence " $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}gc(t)=gc^\prime(0) $ by $\Bbb R-$linearity and Proposition 8.15 "  ?
here, $g$ is a matrix, $c^\prime(t)$ is not the calculus derivative(derivative of a real-valued function), but the velocity vector(linear map of tangent spaces)

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Proposition 8.15  as follows

[image]

Comment: You may treat $g$ as a "constant", since all its entries are independent of $t$.

Comment: Cool. Someone else is learning this book! You can check out my questions if you want. For example, is $(0,1) \cup \{2\}$ a manifold? If so, then what is its dimension? Haha

Comment: to Loring W. Tu,  If a topological manifold has several  connected  components, possible for component to have a different dimension,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g$ have entries $(g)_{i,j}$, and similarly for each $t$ let the value of the curve $c(t)$ have entries $(c(t))_{i,j}$. Then the formula for matrix multiplcation says
$$
(g c(t))_{i,j} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (g)_{i, k} (c(t))_{k, j}.
$$
Differentiating this we obtain (we can differentiate a matrix by differentiating it entrywise)
$$
\frac{d}{d t} (g c(t))_{i,j} = \frac{d}{d t}\sum_{k = 1}^n (g)_{i, k} (c(t))_{k, j} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (g)_{i, k} \frac{d}{d t}(c(t))_{k, j},
$$
since each of the entries $(g)_{i, k}$ are just constant. But the entries $\frac{d}{d t}(c(t))_{k, j}$ are exactly the entries of the matrix $c'(t)$, so we obtain
$$
\frac{d}{d t} (g c(t))_{i,j} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (g)_{i, k} (c'(t))_{k, j} = (g c'(t))_{i,j}.
$$
Hence the derivative at $0$ the entries are $(g c'(0))_{i,j}$, i.e. $\frac{d}{d t}\lvert_{t = 0} g c(t) = g c'(0)$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot!   $c′(t)$ is  the velocity vector(linear map of tangent spaces)